# JWST - batteries?

Tags: james-webb-telescope, battery

I am interested in how batteries might be used on the JWST. A few questions come to mind:

1. Does the JWST have onboard batteries?

If so,

2. What kind of batteries are they?
3. Are they rechargeable?

If so,

4. How are they recharged? … from solar panels? … from reclaiming dumped energy from reaction wheels?

Finally,

5. If there are batteries in use on the JWST, what major (and/or minor) systems depend on them?

Another way of asking (5) might be, if there weren’t batteries on the JWST, what wouldn’t work??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[JWST uses "ABSL™ 8s44p rechargeable Li-ion batteries"](https://investor.enersys.com/news-releases/news-release-details/enersysr-absltm-lithium-ion-li-ion-batteries-successfully-launch), that's 8 series by 44 parallel (352 total) 18650 cells.

The particular Sony 18650 Hard Carbon (Mandrel) or HCM cell has a "nameplate capacity" of 1.5 Ah (5.4 Wh) [[1](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1700&context=smallsat)][[2](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/01_absl_2011_nasa_battery_workshop.pdf)]. Each 8s44p battery unit has a "nameplate capacity" of 66 Ah (1900 Wh).

It's unclear *how many* of these battery units are on JWST. ABSL parent company Enersys says this in a [press release on the launch on JWST](https://investor.enersys.com/news-releases/news-release-details/enersysr-absltm-lithium-ion-li-ion-batteries-successfully-launch):

> EnerSys was selected by Northrop Grumman in 2012 to provide ABSL™ 8s44p rechargeable Li-ion batteries with disconnect relays for Webb, and then awarded a second contract in 2018 for an additional 8s44p battery, tailored to incorporate alternate cell chemistry.

While a [2020 JWST (draft) update [3]](https://science.nasa.gov/science-red/s3fs-public/atoms/files/SMITH-JWST-APAC_June2020_DRAFT_TAGGING.pdf) says this about batteries:

[image: battery change JWST]

> FLIGHT BATTERY CHANGE
>
> Results from recent contingency analyses indicate the amount
> of time to work contingencies in the event of post-launch solar
> array deployment (t +30 min) anomaly has fallen under 3 hours
> with the current ~53 AH battery (HCM Li Ion).
>
> - Fortunately, we procured a spare (Moli-M Li Ion) battery that was of
>   considerably larger capacity ~106 AH – two years ago and it is ready
>   to go. This more than double capacity will provide more that sufficient
>   time to complete all possible contingency operations to recover the
>   solar array.
> - For these reasons, the project has decided to switch to the space
>   battery. GSFC Engineering Directorate and the Standing Review Board
>   have been briefed on this decision.

It should be noted that 53 Ah is *almost suspiciously* 80% of 66 Ah, which is not an unreasonable "depth-of-discharge (DOD)" limit in a contingency scenario.

These sources seem to be talking about the same thing (timelines match), though they are conflicting on implied *battery quantities* on JWST.

**References:**

1. [Pearson et al. "The Use of Small Cell Lithium-Ion Batteries for Small Satellite Applications," (2004)](https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1700&context=smallsat)
2. [Troutman, J. "ABSL Performance Comparison," (2011)](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/atoms/files/01_absl_2011_nasa_battery_workshop.pdf) (slideshow)
3. [Smith, E. "JWST Update (DRAFT)," (2020)](https://science.nasa.gov/science-red/s3fs-public/atoms/files/SMITH-JWST-APAC_June2020_DRAFT_TAGGING.pdf) (slideshow)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, the JWST has rechargeable batteries, they are recharged from the solar panels.

Using non rechargeable chemical batteries would not make sense.

> The rechargeable batteries of JWST are the lithium-ion type. The
> batteries use the Sony 18650 hard carbon cell technology. The
> batteries are designed to endure spaceflight, and should sustain
> 18,000 charge-discharge cycles.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacecraft_bus_(James_Webb_Space_Telescope)#Electrical_Power_Subsystem_(EPS))

Without electrical power the JWST would be useless.